# How can I more efficently debug "Missing character" errors?

Tags: fonts, debugging

I am working on a rather long paper with a ton of inline math. I have a ton of "Missing character: There is no � in font pplr7t!" errors upon compiling, and I understand that using characters no supported by my font cause this issue.

However, these errors don't seem to come with line or page numbers. Or even indications of what file they originate in as far as I can tell!

For example, here is an excerpt from the terminal output:

```
--- from logfile ---
Missing character: There is no � in font pplr7t!
Missing character: There is no � in font pplr7t!
Missing character: There is no � in font pplr7t!
Missing character: There is no � in font pplr7t!
Missing character: There is no � in font pplr7t!
Missing character: There is no � in font pplr7t!
Missing character: There is no � in font pplr7t!
Missing character: There is no � in font pplr7t!
Missing character: There is no � in font pplr7t!
Missing character: There is no � in font pplr7t!
Missing character: There is no � in font pplr7t!
```

Looking in the log file, I see:

```
...
[12])
Missing character: There is no � in font pplr7t!
Missing character: There is no ~@ in font pplr7t!
Missing character: There is no ~Y in font pplr7t!
<789FIG BigDraft 4>
File: BigDraft.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use BigDraft.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: BigDraft.pdf  used on input line 664. on input line 66
4.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 597.50682pt x 845.04504pt on input lin
e 664.
[13]
...
```

I believe the "[12]" indicates page 12, but I can't seem to find an issue with page 12 reading the compiled version line by line, and so I am a bit at a loss for how to interpret the error message. Unfortunately, I don't have permission to share the source file.

Can anyone help me find the origin of these errors? Or correct any misunderstandings I have?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on page 13 not 12

```
[12]
```

page 12 completed

```
)
```

some input file finished (the full log will show which file) and processing returned to the previous file

```
Missing character: There is no � in font pplr7t!
Missing character: There is no ~@ in font pplr7t!
Missing character: There is no ~Y in font pplr7t!
```

missing characters

```
<789FIG BigDraft 4>
```

image inclusion

Comment: Thank you for the response!

>some input file finished (the full log will show which file)

How does it show this? I've skimmed the log around those lines, and nothing stands out as a file finishing. Is it related to the image?

Comment: @rmueller no  a tex file, when it is `\input` the log shows `(/full/path/to/file.tex ` then when that `\input` ends, the log shows `)`  so the fragment of log you showed  was `)` and the matching `(` will show you which input that was, and the missing characters are just after that